# Setter/Getter for function turns function into a string when the function is called?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm using v8 to create a javascript interface to my C++ app but came across an issue with function callbacks.

I have an object template which has a setter and getter for the object "update" which simply set/get an object handle accessible to both the setter and getter (see "Things I've tried".) An object is instantiated within the global context called "world" from this object template. A script is then run which sets "world.update" to a function with a basic output message. The program then gets the update function and calls it which works exactly as intended - printing some output. The program then gets the update function again, but the update function is now a string - the output from the original call. Trying to call it leads to an exception.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

std::string readFile(std::string fname) {
    std::ifstream finput(fname);
    std::string filestr((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(finput)),
                         std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    return filestr;
}

Handle<Value> print(const Arguments& args) {
    String::AsciiValue str(args[0]);
    std::cout << *str;

    HandleScope scope;
    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}

class FuncWrapper {
public:
    Handle<Function> func;

};

Handle<Value> getWorldUpdate(Local<String> property, const AccessorInfo &info) {
    std::cout << "Get update() [" << *String::AsciiValue(property) << "]\n";

    Local<Object> self = info.Holder();
    Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
    FuncWrapper *fw = static_cast<FuncWrapper*>(wrap->Value());

    return fw->func;
}

void setWorldUpdate(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const AccessorInfo& info) {
    std::cout << "Set update() [" << *String::AsciiValue(property) << "]\n";

    Local<Object> self = info.Holder();
    Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
    FuncWrapper *fw = static_cast<FuncWrapper*>(wrap->Value());

    //Accessor info could be used to get the class here
    fw->func = Handle<Function>::Cast(value);
}

int main() {
    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    HandleScope handle_scope;

    //Add stuff
    Handle<ObjectTemplate> globalScope = ObjectTemplate::New();
    globalScope->Set(String::New("print"), FunctionTemplate::New(print));

    Handle<ObjectTemplate> worldTmpl = ObjectTemplate::New();
    worldTmpl->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    worldTmpl->SetAccessor(String::New("update"), getWorldUpdate, setWorldUpdate);

    // Create a new context.
    Handle<Context> context = Context::New(NULL, globalScope);

    // Enter the created context for compiling
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    Handle<Object> global = context->Global();

    Handle<Object> world = worldTmpl->NewInstance();
    FuncWrapper worldUpdateFunc;
    world->SetInternalField(0, External::New((void*)&worldUpdateFunc));
    global->Set(String::New("world"), world);

    // Compile the source code.
    Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(String::New(readFile("main.js").c_str()));

    // Run the script to get the result.
    script->Run();

    v8::TryCatch try_catch;
    Handle<Function> updateFunc = Handle<Function>::Cast(world->Get(String::New("update")));
    updateFunc->Call(updateFunc, 0, NULL);

    if (try_catch.HasCaught()) {
        String::AsciiValue asciistr(try_catch.Message()->Get());
        std::cout << "Caught1: " << *asciistr << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //Re-calling. Has the same effect as calling worldUpdateFunc.func
    updateFunc = Handle<Function>::Cast(world->Get(String::New("update")));
    updateFunc->Call(updateFunc, 0, NULL);

    if (try_catch.HasCaught()) {
        String::AsciiValue asciistr(try_catch.Message()->Get());
        std::cout << "Caught2: " << *asciistr << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The script (main.js):

```
"use strict";

world.update = function() {
    print("Did a world.update()\n");
}
```

The output:

```
Set update() [update]
Get update() [update]
Did a world.update()
Get update() [update]
Caught2: Uncaught TypeError: Did a world.update()
 is not a function
```

Without the object template (i.e. with just a regular object in javascript without the getter/setter combination) the program functions fine but I'd like to be able to use this to have the script manage callbacks.

Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong?

Things I've tried:

- In the code I use an internal field pointing to a Handle object though I have tried using a global variable and using plain old object handles - no differences were noted here.
- Get'ing the update function but not calling, then get'ing again. This proves the call is part of the cause
- Get'ing and calling, followed by calling from the internal field (no difference.)
- Calling directly from the internal field (worldUpdateFunc.func); first call is successful, after this the internal field is no longer a function (can't figure out what it is as it returns false to all the Is* functions) and the program segfaults somewhere random in V8??
- Removing "use strict" does nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object pointed to by the function handle is being deleted.

The solution is simply to wrap a Persistent instead of a handle, and then call Persistent::New() to create a new instance of the function.

```
class FuncWrapper {
public:
    Persistent<Function> func;

};

...
void setWorldUpdate(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const AccessorInfo& info) {
    ...
    fw->func = Persistent<Function>::New(Local<Function>::Cast(value));
}
```

Thanks to the people at the [v8-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/v8-users) for helping me [solve this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/LWVOUW4Q_54)!